# Open source cursor animations apps

Tags: 11.04

are there open source apps eqivalent to Cursor FX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xcursorgen, it let's you create both static and animated cursors for Linux. A good guide which utilizes xcursorgen is located [here!](http://www.ehow.com/how_5026012_make-cursors-file-ubuntu.html)